# Save 3D object from Paraview for future use in Paraview

Tags: 3d, visualization, paraview

I have some data I would like to visualize in 3D (oxygen values in a water column).  It has the general structure of (x,y,z,d).  I can convert the data to a 3D structure with delauney3D that I can then take slices of or otherwise manipulate to get the visualizations I want.

The problem is that I have over a hundred of these data sets in a time series and it takes a relatively long time to run the the delauney3D filter on just one and I can't seem to save the result of that filter in a way that will run faster once reloaded into Paraview.

Is there a way to save the output of the delauney3D filter that isn't a csv and that will reload into Paraview as a 3D object?

Edit:  I've tried saving it as a .vtu, but get this error:

```
ERROR: In /home/buildslave/dashboards/buildbot/paraview-pvbinsdash-linux-shared-release_superbuild/build/superbuild/paraview/src/VTK/Common/ExecutionModel/vtkExecutive.cxx, line 784

vtkPVCompositeDataPipeline (0x7910cf0): Algorithm 
vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader(0x7b08d10) returned failure for request:    vtkInformation (0x7d56390)

Debug: Off 
Modified Time: 198948
Reference Count: 1
Registered Events: (none)
Request: REQUEST_INFORMATION
ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0
```

Comment: You can save the Delaunay3D output (vtkUnstructuredGrid) as a number of file format without problem. Just click on save data and choose the extension. I would recommend .vtu

Comment: I've tried, but it gives an error when going back to Paraview on windows and linux.

Comment: Can you share a subset of your dataset and a associated pvsm state file that reproduce the error ? Also i would suggest asking this question to the ParaView ML, I do not think it suit stackoverflow.

Comment: What does ML stand for?

Comment: Mailing List https://www.paraview.org/mailing-lists/

Answer (score 0):

Is the connectivity between the points found by the Delauney3D that important? Because you could use a [Point Volume Interpolator filter](https://blog.kitware.com/point-and-smoothed-particle-hydrodynamics-sph-interpolation-in-paraview/) for example to transform each point set into a vtkImageData (*.vti) and visualize/analyze the whole sequence with the fitting tools in ParaView afterwards depending on your needs. With this solution, Paraview will be able to take advantage of the structure of the regular grid and load the dataset faster (the main cost in memory comes from the scalar field). And on top of that, if you choose the same dimensions for each vtkImageData of your time series, ParaView will handle the sequence itself efficiently.